# chip component in fluentui/react

Tags: reactjs, typescript, fluentui-react

In material-ui there is this component called [Chip](https://mui.com/material-ui/react-chip/).

Is there a similar component in fluentui/react?

Comment: Did you try that? https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-chips

Comment: No as i know. :(